# File length is not 0 size but is empty, how to eliminate this?

Tags: perl

I wrote a Perl wrapper applying some unix commands, writing the output to a log file.  However I'm seeing it create some empty file but I'm seeing some of the files being created are not 0 size, it is stating 1byte instead; therefore I'm having problem on using the "if (-s "file") do something else do other thing" for some post processing stuff.  Can somebody help why my code is creating an empty line (I guess, though I already place a chomp there), is there a way to eliminate that empty line so that the output log file will always go to 0 byte if there is no data being captured after processing the unix command?  Or else.. can you suggest an effective way to check if file is not empty for case like this.

```
sub sub_unaccessfiles {
    my ($disk) = @_ ;
    @disk_sorted = split (/\s+/, $disk) ;
    $disk_Name = $disk_sorted[4] ;
    my $aging_disk = basename ($disk_Name) ;
    open (OUT3, ">./diskmonitor_logs/char_disks/aging_files_$aging_disk") || die "Cannot create ./diskmonitor_logs/char_disks/aging_files_$aging_disk: $!\n" ;
    my $cmd_aging_grab = `find $disk_Name -type f -name .snapshot -prune -o -atime +180 -printf '%u\t%s\t%t\t%p\n'` ;  
    chomp $cmd_aging_grab ;
    print OUT3 "$cmd_aging_grab\n" ;
    close OUT3 ;
       ..
       ..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
print OUT3 "$cmd_aging_grab\n" if $cmd_aging_grab =~ /\S/;
```

Comment: Thanks Shawnhcorey, I tried your suggestion and it works just perfect for me to get the 0 size file.  Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your print line:

```
print OUT3 "$cmd_aging_grab\n" ;
```

has a '\n' in it - causing the blank line everytime - even if the content of $cmd_aging_grab is empty

Comment: Thanks Pirhac for explaining the root ause... but I have to insert the "\n" so that the log is readable to user; at the same time I need to check for non blank file to proceed on something else.  May I know anyway to fix this?

Comment: Hi Pirhac, thanks as I already have the solution base on suggestion from Shawnhcorey.  But I'm always welcome if you have any else solution to share.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\n` when writting to output file.

Comment: Hi M42, I have the issue solved, pls see the reply from Shawnhcorey.  Anyway, thanks.